# iOS SocialPlatforms - IPv6 Support

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, app-store-connect, game-center

Our App get rejected because of "We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad running iOS 10.3.3 on Wi-Fi connected to an IPv6 network.".

The step where the app stucks with an IPv6 only connection is when we call the Social Platforms API of Unity.

```
 Social.localUser.Authenticate ((bool success) => {
 // Do Login Stuff
 });
```

Did anyone made the same experience and knows what we need to change to make this IPv6 compatible ? We are using Unity 5.6.3f1.

Comment: It's worth mentioning your Unity version.

Comment: @Programmer Hi, we use Unity 5.6.3.f1

Comment: I couldn't find any know bug for this. Are you sure the problem is  `Social.localUser.Authenticate` ? Other than this, are you using any network API like socket?

Comment: @Programmer we are only using Unity's WWW to communicate with our Server. This is perfectly working with only IPv6 networks - it stucks at the Social API Call.

Comment: Last time I checked this was a `WWW` bug on 5.3 not 5.6. You may need to file for a bug report with Unity if you think this is from `Social.localUser.Authenticate`

Comment: I forget to say that 5.6 is not the latest version. The first thing I would do is update to Unity 2017 before filling for bug report if the problem is still there

Comment: @Programmer Okay, we will update to Unity 2017 and try it again. Thanks!